# API binance P2P I only access a part (only the BUY) and not all of it (BUY and SELL)

Tags: python, json, api, request, binance

I am trying to access the data on this Binance website. It is the P2P: https://p2p.binance.com/en/trade/buy/USDT.

For **BUY** I am using this in python3 (I am getting the data correctly for this section):

```py
import requests


headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "123",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "Host": "p2p.binance.com",
    "Origin": "https://p2p.binance.com",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "TE": "Trailers",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}

data = {
  "asset": "USDT",
  "fiat": "ARS",
  "merchantCheck": False,
  "page": 1,
  "payTypes": [],
  "publisherType": None,
  "rows": 50,
  "tradeType": "BUY"
}


r = requests.post('https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search', headers=headers, json=data)
print(r.text)
```

But then when I want to access this part of the page: https://p2p.binance.com/en/trade/sell/USDT (to SELL), I can't do it. Because when I change in the data the following: `"tradeType": "SELL"`, it still brings me the same values of the BUY. **It never brings me the SELL data.**

And I am not finding out why yet.

Comment: I'm getting `{"code":"083996","message":"Please check the input info","messageDetail":{"title":null,"type":null,"icon":null,"action":null,"linkTitle":null,"linkUrl":null},"data":null,"success":false}` when running your original BUY code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of sending requests to the website itself you can send a request to the source itself. If you check your console while the website loads results you will notice it sends a request to https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search
which returns an array of trade details. I believe this is what you need.

Comment: Is the p2p.binance.com API documented anywhere?

Comment: Binance doesn't have an API for p2p transactions, not that I know of at least.

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on the accepted answer:

https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search

POST fields

```
{
    "asset": "USDT",
    "fiat": "NGN",
    "merchantCheck": true,
    "page": 1,
    "payTypes": ["BANK"],
    "publisherType": null,
    "rows": 20,
    "tradeType": "SELL",
    "transAmount":  "5000"
}
```

`asset:` Currently available asset `USDT, BTC, BNB, BUSD, ETH, DAI`.

`fiat:` Its long, visit [sanchezmarcos](https://github.com/sanchezmarcos/binancio/blob/2959a880cc32c16fb878ad4c7966057a8c9e71ce/src/constants/questions.js#L13-L74).

`merchantCheck:` Well i don't know its use, but value is `null, true, false`.

`page:` The endpoint is paginated.

`payTypes:` An array of payment types example BANK, GoMoney, CashDeposit etc.

**payTypes** depend on fiat used so you might not see some of these but there's a lot of payment types.

`publisherType:` I'm only aware of `merchant`.

`row:` Amount of rows from `1 - 20`.

`tradeType:` `BUY` or `SELL`.

`transAmount:` Filter merchant by amount.

**Note:** The api is for binance internal operation which means it can change any time.

As per the comment, it seems the wrong specification of some values can  cause unknown errors.

Comment: It returns Dear User, this payment method is unsupported on Binance P2P. You can still buy and sell cryptocurrency on our official partner's platform https://www.pexpay.com/en

Comment: @VityaSchel it turns out it only returns this error when requesting "RUB" as value for "fiat" key

*upd*: reverse-engineering api of p2p I found that you just have to find correct `payTypes`, for example `TinkoffNew`

Comment: It's good to know you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I did check the result of the api call and confirm the data is correct except `tradeType`, you did nothing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need use it:

client.get_c2c_trade_history() and go to ['data']
Next step is work like json or dateframe, the column that you need have the header 'tradeType'

Answer (score 0):

the price api is returning is different from what the app is showing.