# Binance API P2P I can´t see the SELL information using Python

Tags: python, p2p, binance

I´m getting stuck on trying to bring P2P selling data from Binance using Python. Running the code below I can bring the information from de BUY section but I´m not being able to see the information from the SELL section. Can you help me?

The following code runs right but it only shows the BUY section of Binance P2P. When I try to use this URL for example (https://p2p.binance.com/es/trade/sell/BUSD?fiat=ARS&payment=ALL) nothing changes.

```
url_2 = 'https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search'
p2p = requests.get(url)
q = p2p.text
w = json.loads(q)
e = w['data']
df = pd.json_normalize(e)
df
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the p2p data you need to POST to https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search

So an e.g.:

```
headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "123",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "Host": "p2p.binance.com",
    "Origin": "https://p2p.binance.com",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "TE": "Trailers",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}

data = {

"USDT": {
    "asset": "USDT",
    "fiat": "ZAR",
    "merchantCheck": True,
    "page": 1,
    "payTypes": ["BANK"],
    "publisherType": None,
    "rows": 20,
    "tradeType": "Sell,

},

r = requests.post('https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search', headers=headers, json=data).json()
```

You can change data accordingly to your needs. (e.g. change "Tradetype" to "Buy") unfortunately the API isn't documented so working out the parameters requires some trial and error. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71872412/18905420) has a good list of the parameters.